# Python Multi threading--what does if exitFlag does here?

Tags: python-3.x

```
exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):`enter code here`
   def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name
      self.counter = counter

   def run(self):
      print ("Starting " + self.name)
      print_time(self.name, self.counter, 5)
      print ("Exiting " + self.name)

def print_time(threadName, delay, counter):
    while counter:
        if exitFlag:
          ***`strong text`***threadName.exit()
        time.sleep(delay)
        print ("%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time())))
        `enter code here`counter -= 1
```

What does the '**If exitFlag:**' does here
I don't understand the use of the 'While counter:
   if exitFlag:' in this section help me out please.

Comment: I think delay and counter are inverted in the function call in run method.

Comment: can you please elaborate!1

Answer (score 0):

`exitflag=0` it's a global variable for the threads. I think it's for controlling the thread when it didn't finish (while counter is `true`).

Answer (score 0):

With 1 Thread object only 1 Thread will run. How python manage it?

```
if exitflag != 0:
       raise Exception
```

> `exitflag=0`  exitflag is a variable. As 2 Thread is started from 1 Thread object, Then exitflag  variable change its value from 0 to 1.